# is it possible to modify an existing email body content using office js through outlook addin?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

Here I have implemented an email tracking system through inserting an image, tracking is working fine. Now i want to delete that image (to stop tracking) while replying on same email.Please help me.

Comment: I dont know, how could be done. But i expect it cant do it :(. You can attak to the problem using php, and read refer or anythig that indicate a respond o anythig

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported to modify existing item content through outlook add-ins api now. If you need it, you can put your request [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Also, you could check if the [outlook mail rest api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) satisfies your requirement. Thanks